# Sum, difference and product of algebraic elements is an algebraic element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I found the proof of the result "the Sum, difference and product of algebraic elements of a ring $S$ over a subring $R$, is an algebraic element over $R$", but I failed to find a polynomial in the ring $R[x]$ to show that result. Can anybody help me to find the polynomials?

Comment: You say you found a proof of the result. Why are you asking this question, then? Do you not understand the proof? If so, you should link to the proof in question, and point out the bits you don't understand.

Comment: @Christopher I think the question is clear. In general, knowing the polynomial equations satisfied by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ does not really help in computing the precise polynomials that $\alpha+\beta$ or $\alpha \beta$ satisfy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason for the proof by Dedekind using finitely-generated $R$-modules is that we cannot explicitly give the polynomial for $x+y$ in terms of the polynomials for $x$ and $y$, where $x,y$ are algebraic integers. Even in easy examples it is difficult to find the polynomial. For example, let $\alpha=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}$. Both summands are integral, with polynomials $X^2-2$ and $X^3-3$ in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$. Do you see what the polynomial for $\alpha$ is?

Comment: You do not immediately see it, but there is a finite algorithm to find it.

Comment: @GEdgar You are right, there is an algorithm of course. But concerning the question "Can anybody help me to find the polynomials?", I am not sure, if this is so useful for $x+y$ in general.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you... I wasted 3 hours in the search of the polynomial. I got your point.